# Using Variable in Fetch

Tags: php, mysql, fetch

```
$pullItem = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM items WHERE item_id = '$itemid'");
while ($fetch = mysql_fetch_array($pullItem)) {
    $statinc = $fetch['statinc'];
}

$pullUserStats = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM userstats WHERE user_id = '$uid'");
while ($fetch = mysql_fetch_array($pullUserStats)) {
    $curstat = $fetch[$statinc];
}

mysql_query("UPDATE userstats SET $statinc=('$curstat' + '$incamount') WHERE user_id='$uid'"); //LINE 76
```

This is where I'm having trouble. I do have some coding in between, but my error is this:
"Notice: Undefined variable: curstat in ..... on line 76"

Comment: is `$curstat` defined before `$pullUserStats` and its fetching while loop runs?

Comment: Have you ever heard of joins?

Comment: Just for the sake of knowledge what is the purpose of + sign there??

Comment: @james - Im going to hazard a guess that $curstat and $incamount are integers - thus that will signify an addition operation in the brackets, meaning $statinc will be set to the sum of those 2 variables.

Comment: @FergusMorrow thanks..but is this normal thing he is doing?

Comment: @james - personal preference I guess! When using `mysqli*` functions I usually generate queries using `sprintf` so don't really need to embed variables in the function call itself. For readability I would probably do the addition prior to generating the query - just because it looks a little neater!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few things wrong with the logic behind this code that make it seem like it's either not coded to look like what it's actually doing, or it's just possibly not doing what you want it to do.

The first thing is that with the way you wrote the code, it looks like you want to loop through a bunch of results in the `while` loops, and when you get to the end of the loop, `$statinc` is the value of the LAST result of the query.

`SELECT * FROM items WHERE item_id = '$itemid'` suggests that you either have a bunch of items with the id field `item_id`, or you named what should possibly just be named `id` as`item_id`.

If it's the second case, your first query that loads the items should actually look like:

```
$pullItem = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM items WHERE item_id = '$itemid'");
$item = mysql_fetch_array($pullItem); //There's only one item to be returned, no need to loop over the array over and over again
$statinc = $item['statinc'];
```

Which also means that your second query should look like this:

```
$pullUserStats = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM userstats WHERE user_id = '$uid'");
$userstat = mysql_fetch_array($pullUserStats);
$curstat = $userstat[$statinc];
```

This leads me to believe that userstat is returning an empty query, and thus in your original code, `$curstat` is never getting set.

```
$increase_stat_to = $curstat + $incamount;
mysql_query("UPDATE userstats SET $statinc=('$increase_stat_to') WHERE user_id='$uid'");
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is self-explanatory really, `$curstat` isn't set. In the while loop, echo out the results of `$fetch[$statinc];` to make sure it's actually returning a valid value. If not, check the syntax of your mysql query. The while loop may not even be executing if mysql_query isn't returning a valid result set, this would explain why `$curstat` isn't set *at all*.

In future with errors like this, echo out the query and any related variables so you can test it in phpMyAdmin to ensure you're generating a correct query.

Despite my answer - **Anther** has posted a lot of information regarding the quality of your code, and I must say - the recommendations are worth following up!